# If $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ in the $L_1$-norm, does $(f_n)$ converge uniformly to $f$ on every compact subset of $D$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the open unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$, $0<r<1$ and 
$\overline{D_{r}} = \{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|\leq r\}.$
Let $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of analytic functions in $D$.
Let $f: D\to\mathbb{C}$ be (at least) Riemann integrable over every closed disk 
$\overline{D_{r}}$, $0<r<1$ (i.e., $\text{Re} f$ and  $\text{Im} f$ are Riemann integrable over $\overline{D_{r}}$). Suppose that the sequence
$(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $f$ in the $L_1$-norm on 
$\overline{D_{r}}$, that is,
$$\| f_n - f \|_{1,r} = \iint_{\overline{D_{r}}} |f_n(x,y) - f(x,y)|\, dxdy
\to 0 \text{ as } n\to\infty,$$
for every $0<r<1$. Is it true that the sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ 
converges uniformly to the function $f$ on every compact subset of $D$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: This is an easy consequence of Mean Value Property of analytic functions: $f_n(z)-f(z)=\int_{\overline {D_r(z)}} [f_n(\zeta)-f(\zeta)] d\zeta$ whenever $D_r(z) \subset D$.

When $z$ is in  a compact subset of $D$ you can make $D_r(z)$ a subset of $D_{\rho}(0)$ for suitable $\rho <1$.